# Xamarin Forms List View Show Different Pages?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

New to Xamarin here. How can I make each item on a listview go to a different page in Xamarin Forms?

For example, something like Facebook app:

[image: Facebook App]

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is using a master detail page for this. Your should take a look at [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page/) Xamarin link about Master Detail Page. Let me know if this is not what you're looking for and I'll give you a solution for a listview. I personally would go with the master detail page.

Comment: How can I put the master page inside a tabbed page instead of it being a navigation drawer?

Comment: I can find absolutely no tutorials on making a master page within a tabbed page anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The main flow is simple. You have your ListView, you attach an event on the ItemTapped to it, in code behind in the ItemTap handle method you can access which item was tapped and with that information you decide where you want to navigate.

```
void Handle_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    // Item tapped
    var item = e.Item as YourItemThatWasBinded;

    if (item == null) return;

    // Choose the page to navigate to based on the item selected.
    // You decide what logic use inside this method if can be as simple using IFs.
    var page = GetPageToNavigateWithItem(item);

    // Navigate
    Navigation.PushAsync(page);
}
```

Comment: How would I go about binding a page to a list view item, then getting that page?